# Update values in a table based on a self-join query to itself in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, self-join

I have a table that contains logged events for manufactured items.  We consider each event as having 2 statuses that are based on detail and calculations from the prior logged events for the same item.  So, I've developed a SELECT query that uses multiple self-joins to analyze factors from prior events relative to each event, and calculates the statuses.  But because this query is relatively slow, I have added 2 status columns, and I want to UPDATE the columns with the calculated statuses well after the events happen.  This way I can get fast reports later on the status columns instead of having to run all the calculations each time.

Here would be my table:

```
CREATE TABLE ItemLog
(
   ItemID decimal(11) NOT NULL,
   MessageTime DATE NOT NULL, 
   Temperature float(7), 
   Voltage float(7),
   Status1 VARCHAR2(10 BYTE), 
   Status2 VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
   CONSTRAINT "ItemLog_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ItemID ", "MessageTime ")
);
```

My SELECT calculation query is something like this:

```
SELECT ItemID, MessageTime, 
    CASE WHEN A.Voltage<B.Voltage and A.Voltage<C.Avg_Voltage and C.SD_Voltage<5 THEN 'Good' ELSE 'Bad' END Calculated_Status1, 
    CASE WHEN A.Temperature<B.Temperature and A.Temperature>C.Temperature and C.SD_Temperature>10 THEN 'Good' ELSE 'Bad' END Calculated_Status2 
FROM ItemLog A,
   (SELECT F.ItemID,
        F.MessageTime Key_MessageTime,
        S.Voltage,
        S.Temperature
    FROM ItemLog F,
        ItemLog S
    WHERE F.ItemID=S.ItemID 
        and S.MessageTime=
            SELECT MAX(MessageTime)
            FROM ItemLog
            WHERE ItemID=F.ItemID
               and MessageTime<F.MessageTime
               and Voltage<12
               and Temperature<125
    ) B,  -- Returns the Voltage and Temperature from the prior time it was <12 and <125
   (SELECT K.ItemID, K.MessageTime,
        AVG(L.Temp) Avg_Temperature, STDDEV(L.Temperature) SD_Temp, 
        AVG(L.Voltage) Avg_Voltage, STDDEV(L.Voltage) SD_Voltage 
    FROM ItemLog K,
        ItemLog L
    WHERE K.ItemID=L.ItemID 
        and L.MessageTime=
            SELECT MAX(MessageTime)
            FROM ItemLog
            WHERE ItemID=K.ItemID
               and MessageTime<K.MessageTime
    GROUP BY K.ItemID, K.MessageTime
     ) C  -- Returns the Voltage and Temperature stats from all prior messages
   (SELECT ItemID 
    FROM ItemLog
    WHERE Voltage>40
     ) D  -- Returns all ItemID where Voltage was ever >40, to exclude them
WHERE A.ItemID=B.ItemID and A.MessageTime=B.MessageTime
  and A.ItemID=C.ItemID and A.MessageTime=C.MessageTime
  and A.ItemID=D.ItemID(+) and D.ItemID IS NULL
```

So, the question is, how can I update the Status1 and Status2 columns in the table to be the Calculated_Status1 and Calculated Status2 columns?  I've tried taking my calculation query and joining it to the table by the 2 primary keys, but I get the "ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table" error.

```
UPDATE ( 
    SELECT U.*,
        V.Calculated_Status1
        V.Calculated_Status2
    FROM ItemLog U,
        ( <calculation query above> ) V
    WHERE U.ItemID=V.ItemID and U.MessageTime=V.MessageTime )
SET U.Status1=V.CalculatedStatus1,
    U.Status2=V.CalculatedStatus2
```

I could imagine an UPDATE with a `SET Status1=(SELECT...` but that would need some sort of correlated WHERE for the ItemID and MessageTime, and I'd expect it to run horribly slow.  It would seem that there should be a more direct way to do this?

Comment: I would suggest that you ask another question with sample data and desired results.  It is quite possible that your query can be sped up without creating new columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the solution you are looking for can be served up using MERGE statement. I hope the query which you have posted is correct. I have build the solution on top of the query. Let me know if this helps.

```
MERGE INTO ItemLog it USING
(SELECT ItemID, MessageTime, 
    CASE WHEN A.Voltage<B.Voltage and A.Voltage<C.Avg_Voltage and C.SD_Voltage<5 THEN 'Good' ELSE 'Bad' END Calculated_Status1, 
    CASE WHEN A.Temperature<B.Temperature and A.Temperature>C.Temperature and C.SD_Temperature>10 THEN 'Good' ELSE 'Bad' END Calculated_Status2 
FROM ItemLog A,
   (SELECT F.ItemID,
        F.MessageTime Key_MessageTime,
        S.Voltage,
        S.Temperature
    FROM ItemLog F,
        ItemLog S
    WHERE F.ItemID=S.ItemID 
        and S.MessageTime=
            SELECT MAX(MessageTime)
            FROM ItemLog
            WHERE ItemID=F.ItemID
               and MessageTime<F.MessageTime
               and Voltage<12
               and Temperature<125
    ) B,  -- Returns the Voltage and Temperature from the prior time it was <12 and <125
   (SELECT K.ItemID, K.MessageTime,
        AVG(L.Temp) Avg_Temperature, STDDEV(L.Temperature) SD_Temp, 
        AVG(L.Voltage) Avg_Voltage, STDDEV(L.Voltage) SD_Voltage 
    FROM ItemLog K,
        ItemLog L
    WHERE K.ItemID=L.ItemID 
        and L.MessageTime=
            SELECT MAX(MessageTime)
            FROM ItemLog
            WHERE ItemID=K.ItemID
               and MessageTime<K.MessageTime
    GROUP BY K.ItemID, K.MessageTime
     ) C  -- Returns the Voltage and Temperature stats from all prior messages
   (SELECT ItemID 
    FROM ItemLog
    WHERE Voltage>40
     ) D  -- Returns all ItemID where Voltage was ever >40, to exclude them
WHERE A.ItemID=B.ItemID and A.MessageTime=B.MessageTime
  and A.ItemID=C.ItemID and A.MessageTime=C.MessageTime
  and A.ItemID=D.ItemID(+) and D.ItemID IS NULL)z
ON
(it.ItemID = z.ItemID AND it.MessageTime = z.MessageTime)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET it.STATUS1 = z.Calculated_Status1,
       it.STATUS2 = z.Calculated_Status2;
```

Comment: That seemed to work, but only when I had a relatively small number of total records in ItemLog.  As in, when ItemLog has 1200 events, and I only ran the query to update 7 of them (by including a BETWEEN criteria in the calculation query or on the `it` table in `ON` condition), it took 4 seconds.  When ItemLog had 2500 rows, the same 7 rows took 21 seconds to update. Taking out the criteria so that all 2500 rows updated took 40 seconds.  So, somehow the JOIN must be off.

Comment: Yes for that we need to try to optimize the query to enhance the performance.

Comment: Your suggestion with the merge ultimately answered the question I asked, and I'll work with the performance parts.  Thank you!